# how we can we access private doctor method through main method in c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace doctor_inheritance
{
    class nurse:doctor
    {
        private void ret()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
            records();
        }
    }
    class doctor
    {
        //this is the secret message applied only to the doctors
        int name, specialization;
        private void records()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("these are the records maintained by doctors which cannot be accessed by others");
        }
    }
    class patient:doctor
    {
       public void patients()
        {
          //  doctor d = new doctor();
            records();
            Console.WriteLine("PATIENTS ");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            patient p = new patient();
              doctor d = new doctor();
            d.records();
            // p.records();
            p.patients();
            Console.ReadLine();
    }

    }
}
```

In this section of code i have done separate class for doctor,patient where doctor can access doctor's information but patient cannot access doctor information when i try to compile the code it is showing the error please help me to solve the error

Comment: You will need to read about [Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers) and how do they work.

Comment: Nurses and Patients aren't types of Doctor.  I suspect that there are more intuitive ways to construct your hierarchy.

Comment: Add the error message, line and stack trace to the question.

Comment: Please change the title of the question, doctor is the term for your concrete class

Comment: Are you even able to access private `records` method on doctor object? On the side not patient and doctor are two different entities. My suggestion is to rethink the design and do not inherit doctor class into patient class.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: You should embrace c# naming conventions as soon as possible.